# Run function after other function completes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to run the a function after another function completes. I've found the way below of achieving it but my issue is that I want to use the output of the getLocation function as the argument for the update function, station in this case.

Is there a way I can run the code like this and assign a variable to the output of the getLocation function?

```
function giveAddress(){
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:5000/api/stations', function(json) {
        {
            $.when($.ajax(getLocation(json))).then(function () {
                update(station);
            });
        })
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `getLocation` return? Is it a Promise?

Comment: It returns a string, the name of the station

Comment: ``.then`` or ``.success`` or ``.error``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use callbacks if you have Promises

```
function giveAddress(){
    return $
     .getJSON('http://localhost:5000/api/stations') // first request
     .then(getLocation) // extract location
     .then(function(location) {
       return $.ajax(location)
         .then(function(){return location}) // second request still return location
     })
     .then(update)
}
```

or if you need to use the result of getting `location`

```
function giveAddress(){
    return $
     .getJSON('http://localhost:5000/api/stations') // first request
     .then(getLocation) // extract location
     .then(function(location) {
       return $.ajax(location)
         .then(function(data){return {
            location: location,
            data: data}
         }) // keep location and data
     })
     .then(function(result) {
       // use result.data 
       update(result.location)
     })
}
```

Comment: Apologies if this is a stupid question but how would I use the JSON as an input to the getLocation function in this scenario?

Comment: @Reggie automagically. `getJSON` returns Promise-like thenable object that resolves with object (not JSON but already parsed) it got from backend. Notice I'm passing `getLocation` itself `.then(getLocation)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to add a `data` argument to the promise `then` callback function and then pass it to your second function:

```
function giveAddress(){
$.getJSON('http://localhost:5000/api/stations', function(json) {
    {
        $.when($.ajax(getLocation(json))).then(function (data) {
            update(data);
        });
    })
}
```

Comment: When I print the "data" variable to the console it prints the html of the page whereas the getLocation function normally just prints the station name as a string. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: Maybe you are returning a wrong result in your web service!?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is just take the response that your function getLocation is returning in the promise .then() and pass it to the update function

```
function giveAddress(){
  $.getJSON('http://localhost:5000/api/stations', function(json) {
  {
     $.when($.ajax(getLocation(json))).then(function (response) {
       update(response);
     });
  })
}
```